# how to write getter and setter containing mutex.withLock in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, getter-setter, kotlin-coroutines

I'd like to have a synchronised access to a variable that represents my state from coroutines. How can I fix this?

```
private var myState: MyState? = null
    get() = mutex.withLock {
        return@withLock myState
    }
    set(value) = mutex.withLock {
        field = value
    }
private val mutex = Mutex()
```

right now I get `Suspend function 'withLock' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function` message.
If not possible any alternative elegant solutions?

Comment: `Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of whether they are implemented as 32-bit or 64-bit values.` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7, you don't need mutex here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call suspend function in a non-suspending context. You can use `runBlocking`.

```kotlin
private var myState: MyState? = null
    get() {
        return runBlocking {
            mutex.withLock {
                myState
            }
        }
    }
    set(value) {
        runBlocking {
            mutex.withLock {
                field = value
            }
        }
    }
private val mutex = Mutex()
```

NOTES:

You might be better off changing the property to two suspend functions (getter/setter), instead of using `runBlocking`.
All depends on the context in which you call `myState`.

You also want to consider voting for [KT-15555](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15555).

Comment: From documentation of `runBlocking`: `Runs a new coroutine and blocks the current thread interruptibly until its completion. This function should not be used from a coroutine. It is designed to bridge regular blocking code to libraries that are written in suspending style, to be used in main functions and in tests.`
So using `runBlocking` i then cannot get/set the variable from a coroutine. 
As you suggest much better at that point two suspend functions (getter/setter)

Comment: It's not that you *can not*, it is that you *should not*. (Unless your dispatcher is single threaded, then it'll deadlock).
If you're calling from other coroutines then you definitely want two suspend functions.
I've also updated my answer with a link you might want to see.